# Django template link with if else statement

Tags: django, django-templates

Lets say I have code in template like this:

```
<a href="#">
    {% if request.user.first_name or request.user.last_name %}
        {{ request.user.first_name }} {{ request.user.last_name }}
    {% else %}
        {{ request.user }}
    {% endif %}
</a>
```

Problem with this code is that it adds trailing space to link, so link looks like *link*_ with underline at the end.

How do I remove such trailing spaces? `{% spaceless %}` tag doesn't quite help here because it only removes spaces between tags.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I actually found simple solution for my problem.

```
<a href="#">{% spaceless %}
    {% if request.user.first_name or request.user.last_name %}
        {{ request.user.first_name }} {{ request.user.last_name }}
    {% else %}
        {{ request.user }}
    {% endif %}
{% endspaceless %}</a>
```

By placing spaceless tag inside it strips the string it gets. Placing outside

Answer (score 1):

As a possible variant of decision:
http://www.soyoucode.com/2011/minify-html-output-django

Or you could try to create your own tag if there are no such tags:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/

Answer (score 0):

Quick workaround: Use html comments to "escape" the unnecessary whitespace.
Probably better solution: Create a template tag that holds this conditional.

Answer (score 0):

Seconding the usage of a single template tag - it'd be good (and pretty easy) to remove this logic from the template.

Although, doesn't just using `{{ request.user }}` give exactly the same result as what you're doing here?

Comment: In django 1.3 `__unicode__` method of User model returns self.username

Comment: @marltu - pretty sure it's always been that way.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of if-else block try to use shorter version:

```
{{ user.get_full_name|default:user.get_username }}
```